# Why is the same page referenced 3 times?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, language, hreflang

On my Drupal 8 site, I activated the French and English language.

When I type in google :

```
site:example.com
```

I get 3 times the same results per page of my site :

- `https://www.example.com`
- `https://www.example.com/en`
- `https://www.example.com/fr`

Why is the same page referenced 3 times ?

Will this create problems for SEO ?

In google search console it is written "Pages with meta tags duplicate description" with the results below :

[image]

"Pages with duplicate title tags" :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as this URLs have different content (English, French and the default language) it's ok. From an SEO point of view, the URLs architecture is correct.

Make sure you also use the [hreflang tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) in all URLs.

> If you have multiple versions of a page for different languages or regions, tell Google about these different variations. Doing so will help Google Search point users to the most appropriate version of your page by language or region.

Comment: Thank you, but I have very strange results. I updated my question.

Comment: You have the same title, so I guess the content is also identical in the three pages. That's duplicate content and would make impossible to rank. Make sure each URL has unique and translated content. Check this post: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en

Comment: How to do if the site is in french by default? url `https://www.example.com/fr` is necessarily identical to url `https://www.example.com`. I added a screenshot to my question. This is a page available only in French

Comment: https://www.s1biose.com/fr/article/la-bergamote-pour-lutter-contre-le-cholesterol

Comment: If the site is only in one language, then, disable the French and English language an you will only have one URL structure

Comment: It's an editorial site. The editor can translate his content if he wishes. So some page is accessible in English and some in French or both.